# Question about the exponents n in Mersenne Primes.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, mersenne-numbers

I am starting to study Mersenne primes, and I am wondering if there is a pattern in which exponents give rise to a Mersenne prime or if I am missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Nobody even knows if there are infinitely many mersenne primes, let alone a simple rule for predicting them.

Comment: So are they found just by trial and error?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The exponents must be prime.  Besides that, I wish I knew.  There are computational tests for primality specific to Mersenne numbers

Comment: More or less, sure.   [here](https://oeis.org/A000043) is a list of the (modest sized) Mersenne exponents, just for the record.

Comment: Thanks for showing me that. So are these found primarily by testing for them with computers? I can't imagine that they would be easy to find by hand after the first few.

Comment: See this [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971760/is-it-true-that-2p-1-is-a-prime-number/971764#971764)

Comment: No, there is no pattern. If there were some , we would know all Mersenne primes and the prime hunt for ever larger primes would be over. There is a substantial restriction (the exponent must be prime) and we know them all upto millions of digits. But there is no pattern we can use to find more of them.

Answer (score 5):

The exact pattern isn't known, but we can say a few things:

- Exponents must be prime ( defining quality of a Mersenne number in some cases). as :

$$2^{ab}-1=2^{ab-a}(2^a-1)+2^{ab-a}-1$$

- Exponents can't be in the middle of Cunningham chains of first kind , as then they'll be of form $p=4c+3$, and have $2p+1$ prime . This makes the latter a divisor of the Mersenne number in question ( or the Mersenne number if $p=3$ the one exception).
- Exponents can't be at the start of a Cunningham  chain of first kind, unless of form $4d+1$  as otherwise you can use the same rule as previous.
- Divisors of Mersenne numbers of prime exponent $p$ ,take on form $2kp+1$ for $k\equiv 0,-p\pmod 4$ and that makes them 1 or 7 mod 8.
- Double, triple, and higher order Mersenne numbers, that can be written with Mersenne number exponent have factors that can be written in the same form with $p=2jr+1$, $r$ the Mersenne exponent of the Mersenne exponent, ...
- Mersenne primes, pass the Lucas-Lehmer primality test. and are trial factored to high bit levels to avoid the test as much as possible. ( with modern changes to testing including GPU use, and PRP test use at last check).
- There are heuristic of where the next exponent should be, but nothing conclusive.

**EDIT**

to answer your question the last one found by hand was $M_{127}$ or $170141183460469231731687303715884105727$ if you prefer.

Comment: Only about 25 quadrillion candidate factors for that last number.  But that's without using most primes being of form $6k\pm 1$ otherwise it falls below 18 quadrillion.

Comment: By the way , someone factored $2^{67}-1$ within the Sundays of three years (of course without electronic help)