# About how much time would it take to test the primality of a billion digit Mersenne number with a typical processor?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms, primality-test, mersenne-numbers

I'm wondering how long it might take to run a Lucas Lehmer primality test on a one billion digit Mersenne prime using a 3.0 ghz processor.

Comment: I'm going with 17 minutes.

Comment: https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=17988 has some discussion of complexity of Lucas-Lehmer, also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas–Lehmer_primality_test

Comment: if it only takes 17 minutes,  it seems like someone should have found a billion digit prime.  where's the hang up?  I guess my next question would be how sparsely distributed they are when you get up that high..?

Comment: If it takes 17 minutes to test one number, and if you have to test a hundred million numbers to find one that's prime, well, all those minutes add up, Sergio.

Comment: It depends on processor type, gpu's are about 100 times faster at TF than a regular processor, and about 4 times the speed at LL ( which GIMPS tried to move away from in the last few years). I'm going with months to years with a normal processor not used 24-7 .

Comment: Gerry, gotcha.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @WillJagy $17$ minutes for a billion-digit number ?

Comment: @SergioCannella With one computer you cannot test a billion digit mersenne number in a resaonable time. In fact, you will have already difficulties to even store this number and to work with it without getting an overflow. Even with massive parallelization, I just cannot believe the mentioned $17$ minutes.

Comment: @Peter neither can I, and I helped James Heinrich speed up his sieve for mersenne.ca though only partially.

Comment: @Gerry with even a little bit of theory you can knock out about 668 of the first 22864 prime exponents as impossibility of making primes with minimal trial factoring ...

Comment: @Roddy, so, you can knock out three percent of the first few prime exponents, leaving you $97\%$ of those first few, and then there are the prime exponents beyond the first few. And even if you could easily knock out half the exponents, half of a very large number of minutes is still a very large number of minutes, right?

Comment: That's literally `if(x%4==3,if(isprime(2*x+1), ...),...)` in PARI GP with the dots suitably replaced. That amounts to conditional check of **theorem 4** on the prime pages. I was already able to.implement that. TF values depend even in $k$ value on $x$.. oh and see Operation Billion Digits at GIMPS.

Comment: Here is an example of a 1 billion digit Mersenne number: https://www.mersenne.ca/exponent/3356310967

Comment: It took about 6 days for someone to verify that M82,589,933 is prime, so if doubling the size of a number takes 4x longer, we are looking at about 6*4^5.34476664 days = 27.1294168 years to LL-test that billion digit Mersenne number (has no known factor).

Comment: If faster technology becomes available, then the LL-test should be faster. Multiplication / modulo a 1 billion digit number must be under a millisecond for any reasonable result (Since that is what the LL-test is: just a bunch of squarings and modulo a 1 billion digit number).

Comment: Also fun to think about, there are about 7 billion people in the world --- if everyone had access to fast computers/machines and LL-tested one possible billion digit Mersenne candidate, we should find one within the next 3 decades.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on too much, to get a good answer:

- Computer memory using the square minus 2 version of the test talked about on the wikipedia page, you'd need about 6.7 Gib ( gibibits) just to hold an intermediate value.
- That also takes about 11 quadrillion register multiplies. If you use grade school style arithmetic, at 3 billion per second, one iteration would take ... somewhere on the order of 3667 seconds (north of an hour) just for the squaring (so probably two if you include carries and adds and shifts for mod).
- You wanted to do roughly 3.32 billion of these right ? So hmmm that's about 757991 years ...  ( No. you wanted to do a 3.32 billion bit number of these...).

Thankfully, we have quicker versions, and could find a potential factor by then...

**Comments**

- Even 64 bit registers would take about 189500 years without optimizations.
- Even 512 bit bus doesn't get us below 2690 years without better alogirthm implementation.
- Lastly ( might add these as updates), the 4096 bit bus of the nvidia pascal GP100 of 2015, still fails to get it to under 46 years.

**ADDENDUM**

- A space vs time tradeoff could do it all in one iteration ( plus connections to see if it goes to 0). But,would require about 1.2 EiB (
  [exbiBytes](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/binary.html)) all at once ( okay maybe half or less using equality among quadratic residues)
- We can parallel the adds and multiplies as we go to an extent, just need to stay within bandwidth.
- We need not check every prime exponent, if we use [known](https://primes.utm.edu/mersenne/index.html)
  [properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3461574/question-about-the-exponents-n-in-mersenne-primes/) of Mersenne exponents, or Mersenne divisors.
- We can use [matrix multiplication](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) to setup the multiplies.
- Etc.

Comment: And the bottom line is...what, exactly?

Comment: With CPU/GPU advancements, better squaring algorithms, maybe a lower bit count version like $s_n=2s_{n-1}^2-1;s_0=2$, using lower values that square to the same remainder, using logic; And maybe a bit more, we can decrease times dramatically. That's all without touching the TF side of the coin, the Gerbicz PRP test practically replacing LL etc. @Gerry

Comment: oh and dealing with Mersennes, those lower values, are a bittest and a bitxor away.

Comment: in fact @Gerry if we knew more about the quotients when it was prime etc, we coyld use a few things to not have to restart each time.